# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript v/s Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between

1. `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` and
2. `Response.Redirect`?

Which is better?

Answer (score 0):

Only when you set some code for redirect on `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` we can say that the
 `Response.Redirect` is better because its set a redirect code on the header of the page - but also render a javascript for redirect if the first fail.

Also if you only set javascript code for redirect then the page must be first loaded to run it.